# Trigger com verificação de coluna

Tags: mysql, sql

Preciso fazer um trigger no mysql, mas preciso que ele seja executado somente quando houver um update nos leilões, que alterem o status para 3 ou 4. A forma que eu fiz abaixo esta correta?

É do tipo AFTER UPDATE

```
BEGIN
IF (NEW.status IN ('3','4')) THEN

QUERY_AQUI

END IF;
END
```

Answer (score 0):

A lógica está correta. De qualquer forma, segue um exemplo de código:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/10375177/5857023

Answer (score 0):

A forma que está seu código não foi criado `trigger`, para cria-la é necessário especificar o `CREATE TRIGGER nome_da_trigger`

```
CREATE TRIGGER minha_trigger
AFTER UPDATE
ON minha_tabela FOR EACH ROW

BEGIN
    IF (minha_tabela.status IN ('3','4')) 
    THEN

    QUERY_AQUI

    END IF;
END;
```